# Google protobuf how to add sub-children

Tags: protocol-buffers, addition, children

I have the following protobuf definition

```
message test {
repeated string fruit = 1 [(order_is_significant) = true]
}
```

I want to add apple,pear to protbuf and the output should look like

```
  "test": [
  {
    "fruit": [
    "apple",
    "pear"
  ]
  "rank": 1
   }
```

I tried to add using test.addFruit("apple") and test.addFruit("pear") method but the output looks like

```
test {
  fruit: "apple"
  fruit: "pear"
  rank: 1
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is in protocol buffer text format. What you want looks like json. So you seem to need some kind of json serializer for protobuf.

C++: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.json_util

Java: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/

You'll find formatters for other languages in the left pane of the C++ link.